# Excel chart by date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to make a chart that represents our company's order forecast. I want the chart to be a pivot chart so that it automatically updates. I have a pretty in depth table that will be driving the chart, but the main two pieces of information that I will take from each record are quantity and ship date. What I want the table to display is the total number of pieces we are supposed to ship each week. Additionally the values that are charted will need to be filtered based on weather they have already shipped and what type of unit they are. A starting point would be hugely helpful, or if someone could just point me towards some resources that would be great too. Thanks.

Comment: pretty hard to do much with no idea how your pretty in depth table is structured

Answer (score 1):

Start with learning the basics of Pivots in Excel, for that I would suggest:

[PivotTable II: Filter PivotTable report data in Excel 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/pivottable-ii-filter-pivottable-report-data-in-excel-2007-RZ010208048.aspx)

[PivotTable III: Calculate data in PivotTable reports in Excel 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/pivottable-iii-calculate-data-in-pivottable-reports-in-excel-2007-RZ010210288.aspx)

As well for calculating a week number from a date look at the WEEKNUM() function.